# remove quotation marks from jquery array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel, replace

In my function I search with jquery all items of a owl carousel and take from the id only the available numbers. Because I only need the ID numbers of the items. I send the ID numbers via ajax to my php controller for further processing.

```js
var slideArray = $('#categoryInterestCarousel_' + categoryIdOld).find('.interestOwl');

//Step 1: initialize the array
var previewIds = [];

//Step 2: Search for all IDs and add only the id to the array
$(function() {
  $(slideArray).each(function(index) {
    previewIds[index] = $(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g, '');
  });
});
```

As output I get the following array:

```
array:3 [
  0 => "183"
  1 => "198"
  2 => "201"
]
```

I need the array without quotation marks, which it looks like:

```
array:3 [
  0 => 183
  1 => 198
  2 => 201
]
```

Send data via ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/categorie/owl/' + categoryIdOld,
  data: {
    previewIds: previewIds
  },
  success: function(data) {
    //add some data to view
  },
  error: function(xhqr, staus, message) {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhqr.responseText);
    var errors = response.errors;
    for (var error_key in errors) {
      var error = errors[error_key];
      _toastr_new(error, "top-full-width", "error", false, '.toastr-notify', 0);
    }
  }
});
```

get data on Controller:

```php
public function ajaxOwlItems(Request $request, $id) {
  $preview_id = $request->previewIds;
  dd($request->previewIds);
}
```

Where's my mistake? How can I remove the quotation marks?

Comment: What you are really asking is how to convert strings to numbers which would turn up lots of results in a web search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this - you need to cast the string to number - I use `+`

I took the liberty to streamline the code too - for example no need to use `$(slideArray)` since it is already a jQuery collection.

```js
let categoryIdOld =3;
const previewIds = $('#categoryInterestCarousel_' + categoryIdOld)
 .find('.interestOwl')
 .map(function() { return +this.id.replace(/\D/g, ''); })
 .get();

console.log(previewIds);
console.log(JSON.stringify(previewIds)); // still numeric
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="categoryInterestCarousel_3">
  <span class="interestOwl" id="x183"></span>
  <span class="somethingElse" id="x999"></span>
  <span class="interestOwl" id="x198"></span>
  <span class="interestOwl" id="x201"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: if i let the array display in php, the quotation marks still exist. can i remove the quotation marks in the controller somehow?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: if i display the array in the console or in the php controller, the quotes still exist. Is it possible to remove the quotes in the php controller?

Comment: I still do not understand. Did you run my code here? There are no quotes. you can pass them using  JSON.stringify(previewIds) to encode your array in JavaScript, and then use $array=json_decode($_POST['data']);

Answer (score 0):

Just add [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) around the value:

```
$(function() {
  $(slideArray).each(function(index) {
    previewIds[index] = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/\D/g, ''), 10);
  });
});
```

Comment: if i let the array display in php, the quotation marks still exist. can i remove the quotation marks in the controller somehow?

Comment: How are you displaying the JS variable in PHP? That part is missing from your provided code. Because this seems to require a PHP-side solution then...

Comment: I've added the `laravel` tag to your question. Are you sure that the array is transmitted correctly with integers and not strings after adding `parseInt()` on the JavaScript side? Because unless something in your Laravel code is modifying the data, it should arrive as integers and be output by `dd()` correctly.